# Change name background task

Tags: batch-file, taskmanager

I have a bat file that launches a jar file as a background task.
In the task manager, it appears with the name "OpenJDK Platform binary". How do I set a custom name?

```
@echo off
start /b javaw -jar "C:\Test\myTask.jar"
```

This also doesn't work

```
@echo off
start "MyTaskName" /b javaw -jar "C:\Test\myTask.jar"
```

The goal is to launch an java app as a background task/process, not as a service ...

Comment: Have you tried using a title? The command you are using does have that option!

Comment: Didn't work, is not a useful debugging description. Please use the [Edit] facility, provide the code that you've used in trying that, and show us the results of doing so. (It's also better if you do not tag the wrong name when replying). Also you need to understand what your command is doing. Currently you are using a batch file to run a command in cmd.exe, which in turn is running the javaw.exe launcher to run command(s) outside of cmd.exe. I'm assuming you're calling it a background task, when really its just a running without a visible cmd.exe window. Can you explain exactly your task?